# How Should I Show Osm Point Layer in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, style

I've downloaded osm file and extract it to postgres sql. Now I have for layers :
 1 - planet_osm_line
 2 - planet_osm_point
 3 - planet_osm_polygon
 4 - planet_osm_roads

I've added this layer to geoserver and give each of them one sld file as style except point layer.
then I create one group layer in geoserver but after preview layer i have something like this:

[image]

the point layer is shown as red point. what should I do to solve this problem??

Comment: you need to add the osm style for points to the points layer - it should be there with the lines and polygon styles

Comment: i can't find it